# Python -jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, jinja2

so I created a blog with Flask and when I run it locally it works just fine. But on heroku deployment in the logs I get an "raise TemplateNotFound(template)" error.

**run.py**

```
from flaskblog import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '1238944784'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from flaskblog import routes
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

**Tree**

```
----flaskblog (Directory)
        Procfile
        requirements.txt
        run.py
--------flaskblog (Directory)
            forms.py
            models.py
            routes.py
            site.db
            __init__.py
------------static (Directory)
                main.css
------------templates (Directory)
                admin.html
                base.html
                edit.html
                home.html
                post.html
                posts.html
```

And in heroku logs I get "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html" error.

Also here is the project's Github repository: [Github Repository](https://github.com/berkgaffaroglu/flaskblog)

Comment: Can you try without adding the template_ directory

Comment: I believe you mean template_folder="templates". Yes i did try that too, actually I added it to solve the issue. But it is still ongoing.

Comment: I've added a answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a simple typo in every one of your html files.

Some of the html files have this code on top to extend from `base.html` but there is a space at the end

You have written like this

```
{% extends "base.html "%}
```

You should remove the space at the end and change it to this

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
```